# Insert rows for missing dates/times

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I am new to R but have turned to it to solve a problem with a large data set I am trying to process. Currently I have a 4 columns of data (Y values) set against minute-interval timestamps (month/day/year hour:min) (X values) as below:

```
    timestamp          tr            tt         sr         st  
1   9/1/01 0:00   1.018269e+02   -312.8622   -1959.393   4959.828  
2   9/1/01 0:01   1.023567e+02   -313.0002   -1957.755   4958.935  
3   9/1/01 0:02   1.018857e+02   -313.9406   -1956.799   4959.938  
4   9/1/01 0:03   1.025463e+02   -310.9261   -1957.347   4961.095  
5   9/1/01 0:04   1.010228e+02   -311.5469   -1957.786   4959.078
```

The problem I have is that some timestamp values are missing - e.g. there may be a gap between 9/1/01 0:13 and 9/1/01 0:27 and such gaps are irregular through the data set. I need to put several of these series into the same database and because the missing values are different for each series, the dates do not currently align on each row.

I would like to generate rows for these missing timestamps and fill the Y columns with blank values (no data, not zero), so that I have a continuous time series.

I'm honestly not quite sure where to start (not really used R before so learning as I go along!) but any help would be much appreciated. I have thus far installed chron and zoo, since it seems they might be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742725/adding-missing-rows

Comment: I actually found that earlier and must have closed the tab by accident before I could read it! I'll have a play with what they suggest. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Thomas

If I load my data as follows:

`> # set Home directory
> home = setwd(Sys.getenv("HOME"));
> 
> # make path to the csv file
> fpath = file.path(home, "Desktop", "at0901.csv");
> # read the csv file
> at0901 = read.csv(fpath, header=TRUE);`

I then try to convert the 'timestamp' column to POSIXct values as per the post recommended, but get the following:

`ts$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(ts$timestamp, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
Error in ts$timestamp : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Apologies for my cluelessness - I have been thrown this project with very prior coding knowledge!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the easiest thing ist to set Date first as already described, convert to zoo, and then just set a merge:

```
df$timestamp<-as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

df1.zoo<-zoo(df[,-1],df[,1]) #set date to Index

df2 <- merge(df1.zoo,zoo(,seq(start(df1.zoo),end(df1.zoo),by="min")), all=TRUE)
```

Start and end are given from your df1 (original data) and you are setting by - e.g min - as you need for your example. all=TRUE sets all missing values at the missing dates to NAs.

Comment: This worked for me - I now have a complete time series with NAs for the missing Y values. Thank you so much!

Comment: I get 2 hours difference between the starting row at df1.zoo and df2. df2 starts 2 hours later! Any idea?

Comment: I get ``Error in del/by : non-numeric argument to binary operator`` when I do this. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 50):

This is an old question, but I just wanted to post a dplyr way of handling this, as I came across this post while searching for an answer to a similar problem. I find it more intuitive and easier on the eyes than the zoo approach.

```
library(dplyr)

ts <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2001-09-01 0:00",'%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), as.POSIXct("2001-09-01 0:07",'%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), by="min")

ts <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2001-09-01 0:00"), as.POSIXlt("2001-09-01 0:07"), by="min")
ts <- format.POSIXct(ts,'%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

df <- data.frame(timestamp=ts)

data_with_missing_times <- full_join(df,original_data)

   timestamp     tr tt sr st
1 09/01/01 00:00 15 15 78 42
2 09/01/01 00:01 20 64 98 87
3 09/01/01 00:02 31 84 23 35
4 09/01/01 00:03 21 63 54 20
5 09/01/01 00:04 15 23 36 15
6 09/01/01 00:05 NA NA NA NA
7 09/01/01 00:06 NA NA NA NA
8 09/01/01 00:07 NA NA NA NA
```

Also using dplyr, this makes it easier to do something like change all those missing values to something else, which came in handy for me when plotting in ggplot.

```
data_with_missing_times %>% group_by(timestamp) %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),0,.)))

   timestamp     tr tt sr st
1 09/01/01 00:00 15 15 78 42
2 09/01/01 00:01 20 64 98 87
3 09/01/01 00:02 31 84 23 35
4 09/01/01 00:03 21 63 54 20
5 09/01/01 00:04 15 23 36 15
6 09/01/01 00:05  0  0  0  0
7 09/01/01 00:06  0  0  0  0
8 09/01/01 00:07  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: can explain me clearly on the first 3 lines of the code? How are you doing that? I want to do that for different dates for example from 1st March 2017 to 30 September 2017. I'm kind of confused. So, asking you explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the lubridate package, you can generate the Dates in a more intuitive fashion as well. In this code, I demonstrate date generation without the minute and seconds:   `package(lubridate); ts <- seq(ymd("1991-01-01"), ymd("2015-12-31"), by="day")`

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem except that I have another variable in front of time stamp called Product Id and this variable repeats the whole timestamp value for each set. I am trying to group my dataset using group_by and then use the timestamp completion function discussed above, it doesnt seem to work. Can you please suggest, what should be done?

Answer (score 32):

Date padding is implemented in the `padr` package in R. If you store your data frame, with your date-time variable stored as `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`. All you need to do is:

```
library(padr)
pad(df_name)
```

See vignette("padr") or this blog post for its working.

Comment: Thanks @edwin. I had a little trouble with the function not appearing as part of the autocomplete in rstudio. It's fixed now. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be a pretty convenient solution. Unfortunately I get "Error in if (!all(dt_var[1:(length(dt_var) - 1)] <= dt_var[2:length(dt_var)])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: Could you maybe share an example producing this error? Please use the package's github: edwinth/padr

Answer (score 19):

I think this can accomplished by using `complete` in `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
      complete(timestamp = seq.POSIXt(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), by = "minute"), 
               tr, tt, sr,st)
```

you can also initialize your start date and end date instead of using `min(timestamp)` and `max(timestamp)`.

Comment: This answer is super helpful, thanks! When using this, have you ever received the error "Long vectors are not yet supported. Requested output size must be less than 2147483647"? I can't seem to work around this, and I'm only working with a subset of my data as is (to speed up processing until I get the code right).

Comment: I have not yet seen this error, if you can share an example of what you are trying to do, may be it could be looked in to be experts.

Answer (score 2):

```
# some made-up data
originaldf <- data.frame(timestamp=c("9/1/01 0:00","9/1/01 0:01","9/1/01 0:03","9/1/01 0:04"),
    tr = rnorm(4,0,1),
    tt = rnorm(4,0,1))

originaldf$minAsPOSIX <- as.POSIXct(originaldf$timestamp, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz="GMT")

# Generate vector of all minutes
ndays <- 1 # number of days to generate
minAsNumeric <- 60*60*24*243 + seq(0,60*60*24*ndays,by=60)

# convert those minutes to POSIX
minAsPOSIX <- as.POSIXct(minAsNumeric, origin="2001-01-01", tz="GMT")

# new df
newdf <- merge(data.frame(minAsPOSIX),originaldf,all.x=TRUE, by="minAsPOSIX")
```

Comment: Superb, let me dig through that and see if I can understand what's going on and how I can modify it to do what I need. Looks clear (relatively speaking!). Thank you!

Comment: Great! If you find the answer helpful, I'd appreciate you accepting the answer by checking the gray mark to the left. All the best, -Thomas

Comment: This looks like it will work - no errors, just a few issues. I actually messed up the date format in my original post - it should be `%y-%m-%d %H:%M`. Regardless, I've edited the code to account for this, and the new timestamps are coming out a little wrong. For example, using data for 2009-01-01 to 2009-01-31 (January 1st to 31st 2009), I get the following as the result in 'newdf': `1     2009-09-01 00:00:00      <NA> NA NA NA NA` - in other words, it is getting the timestamps confused (setting month from 01 to 09) and filling all of the columns with NA even when Y values should be available.

Comment: The code I'm using (trying to process data for all of January 2009) is: `# set timestamps as POSIXct values
at0901mod2$minAsPOSIX <- as.POSIXct(at0901mod2$timestamp, format="%y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="")

# Generate vector of all minutes
ndays <- 31 # number of days to generate
minAsNumeric <- 60*60*24*243 + seq(0,60*60*24*ndays,by=60)

# convert those minutes to POSIX
minAsPOSIX <- as.POSIXct(minAsNumeric, origin="2001-01-01", tz="")

# new df
newdf <- merge(data.frame(minAsPOSIX),at0901mod2,all.x=TRUE, by="minAsPOSIX")`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to substitute the NA values acquired by any method mentioned above with zeroes, you can do this:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

(I orginally wanted to comment this on Ibollar's answer but I lack the necessary reputation, thus I posted as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.zoo <- zoo(df1[,-1], as.POSIXlt(df1[,1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) #set date to Index: Notice that column 1 is Timestamp type and is named as "TS"

full.frame.zoo <- zoo(NA, seq(start(df1.zoo), end(df1.zoo), by="min")) # zoo object
full.frame.df  <- data.frame(TS = as.POSIXlt(index(full.frame.zoo), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # conver zoo object to data frame

full.vancouver <- merge(full.frame.df, df1, all = TRUE) # merge
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar where instead of filling out missing timestamps my data was in months and days. So I wanted to generate a sequence of months that would cater for leap years et cetera. I used `lubridate`:

```
date <- df$timestamp[1]
date_list <- c(date)
while (date < df$timestamp[nrow(df)]){
    date <- date %m+% months(1) 
    date_list <- c(date_list,date)
}
date_list <- format(as.Date(date_list),"%Y-%m-%d")
df_1 <- data.frame(months=date_list, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

This will give me a list of dates in incremental months. Then I join

```
df_with_missing_months <- full_join(df_1,df)
```

Comment: Loops in R are hardly the right answer..I'm sure there's a much more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some advances in handling time series data in R, e.g. the `tsibble` [package](https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibble) added such time series manipulations in tidy way:

```
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)

ts <- lubridate::dmy_hm(c("9/1/01 0:00","9/1/01 0:01","9/1/01 0:03","9/1/01 0:27"))
originaldf <- tsibble(timestamp = ts,
                      tr        = rnorm(4,0,1),
                      tt        = rnorm(4,0,1),
                      index     = timestamp)

originaldf %>% 
  fill_gaps()
```