# r: complete value in missing date

Tags: r, missing-data

In R, If I have this data

```
           date.hour temp
2014-01-05 20:00:00            16
2014-01-06 20:00:00            14
2014-01-06 22:00:00            18
```

and with `seq` I can get a sequence of date time

```
begin <- as.POSIXct('2014-1-5')
end <- as.POSIXct('2014-1-7')
seq(begin, end, by=2*3600)
```

how I can complete the data to something similar to

```
           date.hour temp
2014-01-05 00:00:00            NA
2014-01-05 02:00:00            NA
...
2014-01-05 18:00:00            NA
2014-01-05 20:00:00            16
2014-01-05 22:00:00            NA
...
2014-01-06 20:00:00            18
2014-01-06 22:00:00            14
...
2014-01-07 00:00:00            NA
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert rows for missing dates/times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787038/insert-rows-for-missing-dates-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your sample data frame

```
dd<-data.frame(
    date.hour = structure(c(1388970000, 1389056400, 1389063600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
    temp = c(16L, 14L, 18L)
)
```

then you can just `merge()` that with your sequence

```
begin <- as.POSIXct('2014-1-5')
end <- as.POSIXct('2014-1-7')
comp<-seq(begin, end, by=2*3600)

merge(data.frame(date.hour=comp), dd, all.x=T)
```

by setting `all.x=T`, missing values will be filled with NA.

Comment: ... but If I have many original values, how use line `date.hour = structure(c(1388970000, 1389056400, 1389063600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")`

Comment: I don't understand your question. I just used that syntax to make it easier to make your sample data reproducible. You can import your data how ever you like, just make sure your date values are proper POSIX date values.

Comment: thanks, now I undertand, the original values are not in POSIX, for this reason I convert the seq to string with `comp<- format(seq(begin, end, by=2*3600), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 2):

Or similarly with `data.table`

Your data (from @rawr)

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "date.hour temp
'2014-01-05 20:00:00'            16
'2014-01-06 20:00:00'            14
'2014-01-06 22:00:00'            18", colClasses = c('POSIXct','numeric'))
```

Solution

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(date.hour = seq(begin, end, by=2*3600))
setkey(setDT(df), date.hour)
df[dt]
#               date.hour temp
#  1: 2014-01-05 00:00:00   NA
#  2: 2014-01-05 02:00:00   NA
#  3: 2014-01-05 04:00:00   NA
#  4: 2014-01-05 06:00:00   NA
#  5: 2014-01-05 08:00:00   NA
#  6: 2014-01-05 10:00:00   NA
#  7: 2014-01-05 12:00:00   NA
#  8: 2014-01-05 14:00:00   NA
#  9: 2014-01-05 16:00:00   NA
# 10: 2014-01-05 18:00:00   NA
# 11: 2014-01-05 20:00:00   16
# 12: 2014-01-05 22:00:00   NA
# 13: 2014-01-06 00:00:00   NA
# 14: 2014-01-06 02:00:00   NA
# 15: 2014-01-06 04:00:00   NA
# 16: 2014-01-06 06:00:00   NA
# 17: 2014-01-06 08:00:00   NA
# 18: 2014-01-06 10:00:00   NA
# 19: 2014-01-06 12:00:00   NA
# 20: 2014-01-06 14:00:00   NA
# 21: 2014-01-06 16:00:00   NA
# 22: 2014-01-06 18:00:00   NA
# 23: 2014-01-06 20:00:00   14
# 24: 2014-01-06 22:00:00   18
# 25: 2014-01-07 00:00:00   NA
```