# Fill missed dates in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Jmbg = c("0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", 
"0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", 
"0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", 
"0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", 
"0402977385033", "0402977385033", "0402977385033", "2607954335134", 
"2607954335134", "2607954335134", "2607954335134", "2607954335134"
), DatumOd = structure(c(11260, 11457, 11503, 11603, 11696, 11826, 
11875, 12013, 12043, 12133, 12225, 12225, 12317, 12408, 12499, 
13878, 14425, 16203, 10915, 11687, 12372, 13878, 15217), class = "Date"), 
    DatumDo = structure(c(11455, 11502, 11520, 11695, 11800, 
    11941, 12012, 12042, 12132, 12224, 12225, 12316, 12407, 12498, 
    13877, NA, NA, NA, 11686, 12371, 13877, NA, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(
    Jmbg), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:17, 18:22), group_sizes = c(18L, 
5L), biggest_group_size = 18L, .Names = c("Jmbg", "DatumOd", 
"DatumDo"), labels = structure(list(Jmbg = c("0402977385033", 
"2607954335134")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(
    Jmbg), drop = TRUE, indices = list(c(0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 22L), 
    c(1L, 7L, 11L, 20L, 21L)), group_sizes = c(18L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 18L, .Names = "Jmbg"))
```

First column is id. Second column is the date when some event start and third column is date when the event finished. As you can see, there are some missing values in column `Datumdo`. I want to fill this missing values in the following way: If the value is missing and but the `DatumOd` date is the last for id, it should stay NA. If date is missing and it is not the last `DatumOd` date, there should be next date from `DatumOd` column minus one day.

I tried with `dplyr`:

```
df_2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Jmbg) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(novi_date = ifelse(is.na(DatumDo) & DatumOd != max(DatumOd), "test", DatumDo))
```

but instead of test there should be next date from `DatumOd` column for that id. For example, for the last "test", there should be a date 2011-08-30.
Of course, you can use any other package (data.table...)

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16791674/322912

Comment: I think this is not the same problem because I have to use information from 2 columns not just one as in the example you have linked.

Comment: can't reproduce this on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer using `data.table`. It uses the `shift` function to find the leading date (minus one day) for each row and assigns it to a new column, `dayBeforeNext`, by id. From there, an `ifelse` assigns the new dates to another new variable depending on whether there is already a date in `DatumDo`.

I needed to convert the dates to characters before assigning them, then back to date, because there appears to be an bug assigning date types in `ifelse` statements by reference with `data.table`.

```
setDT(df)
df[, dayBeforeNext := as.character(shift(DatumOd, type='lead')-1), by=Jmbg]
df[, DatumDo := as.character(DatumDo)]

df[, new := ifelse(is.na(DatumDo), dayBeforeNext, DatumDo)]

df[, new := as.Date(new)]
```

Your new `data.table will have extra columns so you can reassign those/remove them as you see fit.

Comment: There are some problems with datees format. I succesfuly found the solution using dplyr: `df_2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Jmbg) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(novi_date = ifelse(is.na(DatumDo) & DatumOd != max(DatumOd), 
                                   dplyr::lead(as.numeric(DatumOd), 1L, order_by = as.numeric(DatumOd)) - 1, 
                                   as.numeric(DatumDo))) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Jmbg, DatumOd)
df_2$novi_date <- as.Date(as.numeric(df_2$novi_date), origin = "1970-01-01")`. I forogt I can just use lag.

Comment: Problems with the dates format in my answer or in the issue to which I referred?

Comment: Yes, there were some problems with date formats, if I have used your code. variable `DatumDo` was smaller than `DatumOd` even if I have used lead instead lag in shift function.