# How to insert missing dates/times using R based on criteria?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, missing-data

A data frame like below. 3 staffs have hourly readings in days, but incomplete (every staff shall have 24 readings a day).

Understand that staffs had different number of readings on the days. Now only interested in the staff with most readings in the day.

[image]

There are many days. It’s wanted to insert the missing (hourly) rows for the most ones on the days. That is, 2018-03-02 to insert only for Jack’s, 2018-03-03 only for David and 2018-03-04 only for Kate.

I tried these lines from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787038/insert-rows-for-missing-dates-times) (even though they fill all without differentiation) but not getting there.

How can it be done in R?

```
date_time <- c("2/3/2018 0:00","2/3/2018 1:00","2/3/2018 2:00","2/3/2018 3:00","2/3/2018 5:00","2/3/2018 6:00","2/3/2018 7:00","2/3/2018 8:00","2/3/2018 9:00","2/3/2018 10:00","2/3/2018 11:00","2/3/2018 12:00","2/3/2018 13:00","2/3/2018 14:00","2/3/2018 16:00","2/3/2018 17:00","2/3/2018 18:00","2/3/2018 19:00","2/3/2018 21:00","2/3/2018 22:00","2/3/2018 23:00","3/3/2018 0:00","3/3/2018 0:00","3/3/2018 1:00","3/3/2018 2:00","3/3/2018 4:00","3/3/2018 5:00","3/3/2018 7:00","3/3/2018 8:00","3/3/2018 9:00","3/3/2018 11:00","3/3/2018 12:00","3/3/2018 14:00","3/3/2018 15:00","3/3/2018 17:00","3/3/2018 18:00","3/3/2018 20:00","3/3/2018 22:00","3/3/2018 23:00","4/3/2018 0:00","4/3/2018 0:00","4/3/2018 1:00","4/3/2018 2:00","4/3/2018 3:00","4/3/2018 5:00","4/3/2018 6:00","4/3/2018 7:00","4/3/2018 8:00","4/3/2018 10:00","4/3/2018 11:00","4/3/2018 12:00","4/3/2018 14:00","4/3/2018 15:00","4/3/2018 16:00","4/3/2018 17:00","4/3/2018 19:00","4/3/2018 20:00","4/3/2018 22:00","4/3/2018 23:00")
staff <- c("Jack","Jack","Kate","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Kate","Jack","Jack","Jack","David","David","Jack","Kate","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","Jack","Kate","David","David","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Jack")
reading <- c(7.5,8.3,7,6.9,7.1,8.1,8.4,8.8,6,7.1,8.9,7.3,7.4,6.9,11.3,18.8,4.6,6.7,7.7,7.8,7,7,6.6,6.8,6.7,6.1,7.1,6.3,7.2,6,5.8,6.6,6.5,6.4,7.2,8.4,6.5,6.5,5.5,6.7,7,7.5,6.5,7.5,7.2,6.3,7.3,8,7,8.2,6.5,6.8,7.5,7,6.1,5.7,6.7,4.3,6.3)
df <- data.frame(date_time, staff, reading)
```

Comment: Did you meant `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);df %>% mutate(date_time = dmy_hm(date_time)) %>% complete(date_time = seq(from = min(date_time), to = max(date_time), by = "1 hour"), staff, fill = list(reading = 0))`

Comment: @akrun, good morning sir. thank you for your comment. it gives me: Evaluation error: could not find function "dmy_hm"...

Comment: It is from `lubridate`.  I forgot

Comment: @akrun. a nice one but it fills for everybody for the 3 days. I want 2018-03-02 to insert only for Jack’s, 2018-03-03 only for David and 2018-03-04 only for Kate.

Comment: Looks like `df %>% mutate(date_time = dmy_hm(date_time), date = as.Date(date_time))  %>% complete(date_time = seq(as.POSIXct(paste(date[1], "00:00:00"), tz = "GMT"), length.out = 24, by = "1 hour"), staff, fill = list(reading = 0)) %>% select(-date)`

Comment: @akrun, it does for everybody only for 2018-03-02...

Comment: Can you show the expected frequency

Comment: Do you need `df %>% mutate(date_time = dmy_hm(date_time), date = as.Date(date_time)) %>% split(.$date, .$staff, drop = TRUE) %>% map_df(~ .x %>% group_by(staff) %>% complete(date_time = seq(as.POSIXct(paste(date[1], "00:00:00"), tz = "GMT"), length.out = 24, by = "1 hour"), fill = list(reading = 0))) %>% select(-date)`

Comment: @akrun, thanks again. please see the question edited with wanted result. (your latest code fill everybody for all days)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166239/discussion-between-mark-k-and-akrun).

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubts, i posted a soution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option would be to do this separately.  Create a `data.table` of the dates of interest and the corresponding 'staff', and get the full sequence of date time, then we `rbind` this with the original dataset and using a condition, we summarise the data

```
library(data.table)
stf <- c("Jack", "David", "Kate")
date <- as.Date(c("2018-03-02", "2018-03-03", "2018-03-04"))
df1 <- data.table(date, staff= stf)[, .(date_time = seq(as.POSIXct(paste(date, "00:00:00"), 
       tz = "GMT"),
           length.out = 24, by = "1 hour")), staff]

setDT(df)[, date_time := as.POSIXct(date_time, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")]
res <- rbindlist(list(df, df1), fill = TRUE)[, 
     .(reading = if(any(is.na(reading))) sum(reading, na.rm = TRUE) else reading),
         .(staff, date_time)]

table(res$staff, as.Date(res$date_time))

#         2018-03-02 2018-03-03 2018-03-04
#  David          3         24          2
#  Jack          24          1          1
#  Kate           3          1         24

head(res)
#   staff           date_time reading
#1:  Jack 2018-03-02 00:00:00     7.5
#2:  Jack 2018-03-02 01:00:00     8.3
#3:  Kate 2018-03-02 02:00:00     7.0
#4:  Jack 2018-03-02 03:00:00     6.9
#5:  Jack 2018-03-02 05:00:00     7.1
#6:  Jack 2018-03-02 06:00:00     8.1

tail(res)
#   staff           date_time reading
#1:  Kate 2018-03-04 04:00:00       0
#2:  Kate 2018-03-04 09:00:00       0
#3:  Kate 2018-03-04 13:00:00       0
#4:  Kate 2018-03-04 18:00:00       0
#5:  Kate 2018-03-04 21:00:00       0
#6:  Kate 2018-03-04 23:00:00       0
```

Comment: thanks. but the date_time appended is value like 1520200800, instead of regular date/time format. could you please have a look?

Comment: @MarkK  I think I know why it was doing that for you bcz I forgot to paste the date_time conversion line in my code.  Could you please check it now?

Comment: it's ok now! you are indeed a guru!

Comment: by the way, when the original data is big, there's no a way to manually create "stf" and "date". is there a way to generate "stf" and "date" smartly?

Comment: @MarkK Yes, you are get it done by `unique(df$staff)` and the corresponding dates it seems to be custom made

Comment: gurus like you make the world beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Identify each daily hour and all staff members

```
date_h<-seq(as.POSIXlt(min(date_time),format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),as.POSIXlt(max(date_time),format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),by=60*60)
staff_u<-unique(staff)
comb<-expand.grid(staff_u,date_h)
colnames(comb)<-c("staff","date_time")
```

Uniform date format in `df`

```
df$date_time<-as.POSIXlt(df$date_time,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Merge information

```
out<-merge(comb,df,all.x=T)
```

Your output:

```
head(out)
  staff           date_time reading
1  Jack 2018-03-02 00:00:00     7.5
2  Jack 2018-03-02 01:00:00     8.3
3  Jack 2018-03-02 02:00:00      NA
4  Jack 2018-03-02 03:00:00     6.9
5  Jack 2018-03-02 04:00:00      NA
6  Jack 2018-03-02 05:00:00     7.1
```

Comment: ,thank you. but it fills for everybody for 2018-03-02 and 2018-03-03. 2018-03-04 shows uneven numbers for everybody...

Comment: Ok, try all.x=T

Comment: Trouble could be related to this kind of repeated data: 2018-03-04 00:00:00 David     6.7 - 2018-03-04 00:00:00 David     7.0; same data same staff member