# How to insert all missing weeks between new and old date in a datatable to calculate weekly stock R

Tags: r

So I have a datatable df with column ID DATE and STOCK

In this table, the same ID has multiple values with their date and stock:

```
ID        DATE        STOCK
a1     2017-05-04       1
a1     2017-06-04       4
a1     2017-06-05       1
a1     2018-05-04       1
a1     2018-06-04       3
a1     2018-06-05       1
a2     2016-11-26       2
a2      ...             ..
```

Using lubridate I can get which week a date is as follows:

```
dfWeeks=df[,"WEEK" := floor_date(df$`Date`, "week")]

ID        DATE        STOCK        WEEK
a1     2017-05-04       1       2017-04-30
a1     2017-06-04       4       2017-06-04
a1     2017-06-05       1       2017-06-04
a1     2018-05-04       1       2018-04-29
a1     2018-06-04       3       2018-06-03
a1     2018-06-05       1       2018-06-03
a2     2016-11-26       2       2016-11-20
a2      ...             ..
```

So from column DATE I know my old date is `2017-05-04` and newest date `2018-06-05`, which has about **56.71429** weeks:

```
dates <- c( "2017-05-04","2018-06-05")
dif <- diff(as.numeric(strptime(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")))/(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
```

And my table has only 4 unique weeks, so the idea is to sum stock for each week and insert the missing (57-4=53 weeks) ones with 0 value in stock.

Then I can do the mean of all the weeks like

```
meanStock<- dfWeeks[, .(mean=sum(Stock, na.rm = T)/dif <- diff(as.numeric(strptime(c(min(Date), max(Date)), format = "%Y-%m-%d")))/(60 * 60 * 24 * 7) ), by = .(ID)]
```

But I don't know if it will work, Hope I made it clear and any advice or approach is welcomed.

UPDATE:

This is how I get the max and min date

```
max = aggregate(df$`Date`,by=list(df$ID),max)
colnames(max) = c("ID", "MAX")
min = aggregate(df$`Date`,by=list(df$ID),min)
colnames(min) = c("ID", "MIN")
test <- merge(max, min, by="ID", all=T)
```

Comment: Can you provide a subset of data to work with?

Comment: It's confidential but basically follows same logic as shown in the question for df

Comment: Can you provide at least an example of dataset in usable format (so people won't try to parse the data)?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Insert rows for missing dates/times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787038/insert-rows-for-missing-dates-times); [Fastest way to add rows for missing values in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438969/fastest-way-to-add-rows-for-missing-values-in-a-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1) and heaps of alternatives in Linked therein.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, DATE := as.Date(DATE)][, `:=` (st = min(DATE), end = max(DATE) + 7), by = ID][
  , .(ID = ID, DATE = DATE, STOCK = STOCK, Expanded = seq(st, end, by = "week")), by = 1:nrow(df)][
    , `:=` (WEEK = floor_date(Expanded, "week"), WEEK2 = floor_date(DATE, "week"))][
      WEEK != WEEK2, STOCK := 0][
        , .(SUM_STOCK = sum(STOCK)), by = .(WEEK, ID)]
```

Output (rows for the weeks of `2017-04-02` until `2017-06-11` and `ID` `a1`):

```
          WEEK ID SUM_STOCK
 1: 2017-04-02 a1         0
 2: 2017-04-09 a1         0
 3: 2017-04-16 a1         0
 4: 2017-04-23 a1         0
 5: 2017-04-30 a1         1
 6: 2017-05-07 a1         0
 7: 2017-05-14 a1         0
 8: 2017-05-21 a1         0
 9: 2017-05-28 a1         0
10: 2017-06-04 a1         5
11: 2017-06-11 a1         0
```

Comment: This looks very good But I need to keep the ID as well, also  st = as.Date("2017-05-04"), end = as.Date("2018-06-15") is not the same for each id,

I have managed to get the max and min date I will Update the question

Comment: Check update thats how I get the max and min date for each ID

Comment: Have a look, I've updated the code. Now it runs for each ID, and expands the data by each min + max (I add 7 days to maximum to be sure all weeks are captured, you can filter that out later).

Comment: Thats good but why I have more weeks for ID a1 i know between old and new i have 57 weeks but in df I got more entires?

Comment: It depends on what you take as maximum date for ID a1. If you take "2018-06-05", then R will calculate it to the previous week (e.g. if you do a sequence, you will get the last week in 2018-05, i.e. May and not June). If you want to include the first week of July, you need to add +7 days to "2018-06-05", then also the difference in weeks becomes 57.7 and not 56.7.

Comment: I don't understand, But i do know the number of weeks is calculated from newest and oldest date , what I don't understand how is it possible that there are more weeks in that interval

Comment: You can put end = max(as.Date(DATE))) in the first line instead of end = max(as.Date(DATE)) + 7), and see if you get the result you want. I think in that case you will end up with your desired number of weeks, but you will lose observations effectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184031/discussion-between-programmer-man-and-arg0naut).