# Missing Values in Raw data

Tags: r, missing-data, imputets

So here's my problem:
I have raw data of daily interest rate for the year 2010 to 2019. However, there are several dates that are missing.

`1244  9-Jul-10 5.053 
1245  8-Jul-10 5.007 
1246  7-Jul-10 4.991 
1247  6-Jul-10 4.976 
1248 28-Jun-10 4.850 
1249 21-Jun-10 4.900 
1250 18-Jun-10 5.000 
1251 14-Jun-10 3.800 
1252  9-Jun-10 3.850 
1253  1-Jun-10 3.950 
1254 31-May-10 3.950`

When I import the data on R, it displays 1254 data which is the amount of data that I actually have.

```
interest <-read.csv("C:/Users/SOOGRIM/Desktop/Interest4.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

> interest
>             Date Price
>   1    21-Jan-19 3.550 
>   2    20-Jan-19 3.550 
>   3    19-Jan-19 3.550 
>   4    18-Jan-19 3.550 
>   5    17-Jan-19 3.630 
>   summary(interest)
>        Date               Price             X
>    Length:1254        Min.   :0.861   Min.   : 1.000
>    Class :character   1st Qu.:2.400   1st Qu.: 1.000
>    Mode  :character   Median :2.900   Median : 2.000
>                       Mean   :3.000   Mean   : 3.031
>                       3rd Qu.:3.670   3rd Qu.: 6.000
>                       Max.   :5.674   Max.   :10.000
>                                       NA's   :1222**

However, on converting it to time series, it interpolates the data for the missing dates and results in a total of 3281.

```
interest.ts <-ts(data=interest$Price,frequency=365,start=c(2010,06),end=c(2019,01))
```

> summary(interest.ts)
>      Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>     0.861   2.450   2.900   3.001   3.680   5.674 
>   length(interest.ts)
>   [1] 3281**

This affects my forecast of the interest rate.

I want to be able to identify the missing date in my daily values and replace it automatically in R. I have investigated into the package `imputeTS` and `lubridate`. I don't know what function to use in order to renumber the date and display the NaN for "price" variable respectively.

Then I will use the correct interpolation method which is available in the imputeTS package to interpolate the values for the "price" variable.

Simply I just want to know how to add the missing date automatically in R. As there are over 1000 date missing, it's tedious to do it manually on excel.

Comment: Do you need something more than `is.na` ?

Comment: `is.na` or `is.nan`

Comment: It is very difficult to understand your problem without an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have editted the question. Can you help me please?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787038/insert-rows-for-missing-dates-times/35439235

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742725/adding-missing-rows     I think if you adapt the solutions a little bit they can work for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did not understand your problem completely - but I think this is a problem of implicit missing values.

You have a time series and some dates are missing completely - but not in a way that they are marked as NA, the dates are just not given at all in the time series.
(thus the NA values are only implicitly given)

You can solve this with a **imputeTS** and **tsibble** package combination.

```
library(imputeTS)
library(tsibble)

# Convert your time series or data.frame into a tsibble time series object
x <- as_tsibble(your_timeseries)

# Get the implicit missing values -afterwards you have the missing values as NA
x <- fill_gaps(x)

# Perform the time series imputation
x <- na_kalman(x)
```

Here the tsibble package is used for adding the implicit missing values as actual NA values. Afterwards imputeTS is used to perform the time series imputation (replacing the NA values).

If you only need simple imputation like e.g. a mean you can also do this with fill_gaps directly. Otherwise use some function of imputeTS (e.g. `na_kalman`, `na.interpolation`, `na_seadec`, `na_ma`)